# Eclipse Mars JNI Error

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface, weka

Hi I am working on weka api in Eclipse Mars. Everything was fine until i wrote a class for LinearRegression, just then Eclipse started giving JNI error. Now other classes runs fine but when i try to run LinearRegression class the error pops up. 
The first error is 
**Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check you installation and try again** 
followed by JVM launcher error 
**"A java exception has occurred"**. 
And then a list of errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no/uib/cipr/matrix/Matrix
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.Matrix
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I will appreciate if someone could help me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I got a similar problem.

Comment: Check java class find in JNI layer.

Comment: @Moved can you please elaborate your answer a bit.

Comment: @Aftab when you reference your java class in JNI, check if the signatures are correctly written.